# Please help resolve bottle neck in wait times for Http Responses?

Tags: performance, http, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

As far as a performance issue, the server is performing fine.  With the exception of the http response wait times.  This will become more of an issue as we grow our line of online services.  All things being equal, I’m confused how this new server is it not loading pages as quickly as an older server running multiple websites, logging, etc…

Here is a screen shot from http://www.gtmetrix.com the online testing tool I’ve been using.  These results are consistent regardless of time of day,  The numbers here don’t make sense.  The new site page is 75% smaller, yet its total time to live is only 26ms faster.  In the below image the left side is NEW SERVER, the right side is OLD SERVER
The left portion of the timeline is the Handshaking portion.  So, you can see, the new server, is about the same speed.  The purple middle section, that represents wait time.  It’s about 4 times the delay in milliseconds as OLD SERVER.  The Grayish section on the right represents the actual time to download the file.  You will also notice that the new server is significantly faster at downloading the response, this is most likely due to the 75% decrease in the response size.

[image: GtMetrix Resuts] You can see the complete results for the new server here. http://gtmetrix.com/reports/204.193.113.47/Kl614UCf

Here’s a table of the differences that I’m aware of, let me know if you see one that could be the culprit.  I forgot to add this to the table, but the old server, is in production, right now serving requests, when www.gtmetrix is hitting it.  In contrast, to my New server, which is just me connecting and generating requests.

[image: Server Config Comparison]

My current hypothesis, is that the slowness is caused some combination of the server being virtualized, incorrect IIS settings, or the difference between 32bit and 64bit OSes

Comment: does the app hit any rdbms?? on the same or on other server??

Comment: Yes, both servers hit the same sql box on it's own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK...

The server in in Sarasota(?), the test agent is in Vancouver so roughly 4,356KM apart (as the crow flies) so the best round trip time you could hope for is around 45ms.

Given it won't be a direct route and things like routers etc. will that add latency then the 155ms round-trip you seem to be getting is pretty reasonable.

Looking at the request for the HTML page the 344ms to complete it a pretty good time - basically 114ms to set up the connection, 115ms to receive the first bytes from server and then 155ms to get the complete response.

Unless you get decrease the roundtrip time then this time isn't going to improve much  - have you tried testing from gtmetrix's Dallas server as a comparison?

If it is a slow server response then something like PAL (http://pal.codeplex.com/) is worth using as a first look to see what's happening on the server but I'd also look how quickly the SQL server is responding to the queries that are used on the test page.

A couple of things you want to look at later in the waterfall...

For the two files that are hosted from ajax.aspnetcdn.net it takes longer to resolve their DNS name than it does to download them so you may want to consider hosing them yourself

For the text based content e.g. HTML, CSS, JS etc. what level of gzip compression are you applying and are the compressed files being cached on the server? (the server times for them look a bit long)

Comment: Yes, but why is my Old Server (1995 V6 Camaro) server faster than my (2012 V8 Camaro ZL1).  All these anwers are helpful but they don't address this part of the question.  Which is my whole issue.  I agree 344ms is pretty good.  but considering this new server is far superior to the old server, I would expect the times to reflect that and they just don't.

Comment: Your 2012 Camaro maybe faster than your 95 Camero but to get to China it would still need to go on a freighter which isn't going to get there any quicker. How fast does it load locally?

Comment: You seem to keep ignoring the fact that the old server is handshaking, sending, receiving faster no matter how far away the benchmark server is located.  Than the brand new server....

Comment: That's why I suggested using PAL above... You're not going to get an answer from SO, if you are convinced you have a server-side issue then you need to hire someone to diagnose it...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the complete results, it seems the **lower bound** for the wait times would be **115ms**. Not a single request is faster, most are around 125ms, and judging from the requested resources, there's a lot of static resources as well, so serving the response should not involve a lot of CPU. Even though responses are as small as 123 bytes, there's still this delay.

So it looks like a general issue, possibly not even related to IIS. Here some ideas how I'd try to debug this.

- How long does a ping roundtrip take? (i.e. Is it a general network issue, routing etc.?)
- How long do HTTP requests take when done from the server box (e.g. to localhost)? (If they all take more than ~100ms, start profiling inside the server box)

Comment: Meaning the box that is requesting the page? That's hosted by GtMetrix and I have no way to test for that. As for pinging, that would be difficult, since I would have to ask our hosting agency to enable pinging to the servers. (Which they consider a security risk)

Comment: Edited that part of the answer, that hopefully makes it clear.

Comment: I did local testing and the speeds were fantastic.  Also, I wrote a simple start timer, read a file, write a file, stop timer, asp page. and ran it on both boxes and the times written in the response.write were nearly identical.

Comment: So it looks like an issue outside of IIS' bounds, something network-related perhaps. In addition to timing ping, as mentioned, you could also try to time a single HTTP request to the server's homepage from a couple of hosts, inside the network, outside the network to see whether you can narrow it down to a network issue. In a Unix shell (or in cygwin), a command like `time wget -q -O/dev/null http://204.193.113.47/` would do.